# Reverse Movie in Unity 5

Tags: unity, video

guys! Is it possible to reverse video or apply a rewind in Unity 5? I searched in the web but could not find the solution.

Comment: How are you playing the movie? Are you using a [MovieTexture](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MovieTexture.html)?

Comment: Yeah, I am using MovieTexture

Comment: By "reverse" do you mean "play backwards" or "rewind to beginning"?

Comment: Exactly, "play backwards". When a user clicks a button video shall be played in backwards

Comment: You could create a second video which is backwards and change to it when ever you want the video to play.